# free() invalid pointer C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, free

I have quite strange behavior in such easy code.
Just have a templated class that copies pointers:

```
template <typename T_out, typename Class_type, typename T_in> class C_Ololo{
        public:
        T_out (Class_type::*cxfunc) (T_in);
        Class_type * obj_ref;
        T_out getRef(T_out (Class_type::*func2) (T_in), Class_type * __obj )
        {
            cout << "GetRef in...1" << endl;
            cxfunc=func2;     // Segmentation fault
            cout << "GetRef in...2" << endl;
            obj_ref=__obj;    // Segmentation fault
        }
    };
```

Then just some bare class to call a previous one:

```
class C_Temp{
    public:
    dcxArray1D /* double */  func (double a){
        dcxArray1D /* double */ temp(1);
        return temp;
    }

    void getResult(){
        cout << "GetResult" << endl;
        C_Ololo <dcxArray1D /* double */ ,C_Temp,double> * ololo;
        ololo = new C_Ololo<dcxArray1D /* double */ ,C_Temp,double>();
        ololo->getRef(&C_Temp::func,this);
    }
};
```

Where dcxArray1D is just:

```
typedef vector< complex<double> > dcxArray1D;
```

So - the problem is when i use `double`, everywhere i have `dcxArray1D` now, i dont have any problem. But once i use `dcxArray1D` i have "Segmentation fault" and free(): invalid pointer in first class.

Could you help a little...

Comment: `__obj` is an invalid name (reserved for implementation)

Comment: Just as a tip, instead of using function pointers you might want to read more about [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) (and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)).

Comment: Care to show us where this is *used*? Odds are you're corrupting the heap *there* or near there. As written, all this does is occupy space in a source file.

Comment: @WhozCraig it is a header file. Then i have main.cpp with two lines `C_Temp temp; temp.getResult();`

Comment: So.. stare at your `T_out getRef(...)` method of your template class awhile, then tell us what it returns. More to the point *where it returns it.*

Answer (score 0):

There's no call to `free` in the code you're showing. There's also no call to `malloc`. That's all rather suspicious. The root cause is almost certainly that you're calling `free` on something which wasn't allocated with `malloc`.

Why are you even using such primitive functions? The whole problem would probably go away immediately if you'd stick to standard C++ functionality.

Comment: I dont call `free` - all i have just this header and main.cpp with two lines 
   `C_Temp temp;
   temp.getResult();`
And what do you mean by _primitive functions_ and _standard C++ functionality_ in this case?